# Bulgarian residency card expiring. Can I use my visa-free passport to re-enter the country?

Tags: schengen

I’m a Canadian citizen currently studying in Bulgaria. I’ve been here for the past few years and I renew my residency card each year. My card is expiring soon and I’m graduating.

However the process to actually get my diploma takes a few weeks and my card will be expired by then. I don’t want to go through the hassle of renewing my card for just a few weeks if I don’t have to. I want to leave before my residency card expires and then return to pick up my diploma in a few weeks using just my Canadian passport and the 90 days it gives me.

But does this rule apply to me since I’ve been living here for the past few years? Do I have to wait for another 90 days before I can use my passport to enter? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Under the Schengen rules, you can do that, because periods of stay authorized under a residence card do not count for the 90/180 calculation, but I'm not certain whether Bulgaria, which is not yet part of the Schengen area, applies the same rule.